# Shorter URL in Groovlet

Tags: html, groovy, groovlet

Consider the following Groovlet:

```
html.html
{
  head { 
    title("Groovy Test")
  }

  body {
    center {
      img(src:"getPlot.groovy?name=name&value=value")
    }
  } 
}
```

Is there a better way to generate the URL? I'm looking to eliminate the explicit var/vals from the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [UrlRewriteFilter](http://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/) for this. It's like mod_rewrite but implemented as a servlet filter.